# Insert a new column with generated sequence IDs in mySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have the following records and I need to insert a new column called "records" with generated IDs in an ascending order; how do we do that in "MySQL" database ?

```
TERM_CODE   SUBJ_CODE   CRSE_NUMB   SCHD_CODE       CREDIT_HRS
201710  CHEN                311           L             93
201710  CHEN                311           L             96
201710  CHEN                314           L             78
201710  CHEN                314           L             81
```

to be like below:

```
Record  TERM_CODE   SUBJ_CODE   CRSE_NUMB   SCHD_CODE   CREDIT_HRS
1        201710       CHEN         311         L          93
2        201710       CHEN         311         L          96
3        201710       CHEN         314         L          78
4        201710       CHEN         314         L          81
```

My DDL is the following:

```
Field          Type    Collation    Null
TERM_CODE   varchar(28) utf8_bin    NO
SUBJ_CODE   varchar(20) utf8_bin    NO
CRSE_NUMB   varchar(24) utf8_bin    NO
CRSE_LVL    varchar(50) utf8_bin    YES
PIDM         double                 NO
Count        double                 YES
Earned      varchar(20) utf8_bin    YES
Job_Type    varchar(50) utf8_bin    YES
COST        varchar(50) utf8_bin    YES
COST_DES    varchar(83) utf8_bin    YES
```

Comment: please provide the DDL of your table

Comment: please add it to your question. in a comment it is unreadable

Comment: DDL was added in my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be broken down into three steps:

**1. Adding a column**

Suppose the table name is `table_name`, then to add a column called `records` with type `int`, execute this command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD record int;
```

**2. Updating that column for all rows with a number sequence**

To do this, you will need an additional field. Suppose we choose the name `@rank` for this field. This is how you update that column with a number sequence:

```
SET @rank:=0;
update table_name
set record=@rank:=@rank+1;
```

**3. (Optional) Adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` property**

You might want to add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` property to the record, so that you do not need to manually decide the value of `record`. To do that, the column `record` must be a primary key.

If the table already has a primary key, you must drop it first by using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

And then you can add `AUTO_INCREMENT` property to the record while setting it to primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE record record int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```